# Resizable Containment not working for me

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I am new here so I dont know how its work.
I am trying to resize div but its not resize inside parents properly
Here what I am trying. Can you help me out. I want to resize blue div in full Parent div.
I am not getting what I am missing in code.
Thanks in advance.

```
    <html>
      <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>JS Bin</title>
        <style type="text/css">
          * {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
          }

          #Container {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            left: 264px;
            width: 312px;
            height: 512px;
            background-color: silver;
          }

          #Parent {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            width: 0px;
            height: 0px;
          }

          #resizable {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            width: 256px;
            height: 256px;
            background-color: blue;
          }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="resizableContainer1" style="top: 6px; left: 0px; width: 256px; height: 512px; background-color: red;">
        </div>
        <div id="Container">
          <div id="Parent">
            <div id="resizable"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#resizable").resizable({
        "containment": "#Container"
      });
    });</script>
    </html>
```

Comment: why do you have **#Parent** with a width and height of **0px**. and then your trying to resize its child inside it ???

Comment: I try to change height but its does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about this:

- remove the **width:0;** and the **height:0;** from **#Parent**
- make **#Parent** relative
- change containment to **#Parent**
- remove css **position:absolute;** , **left:0;** , and **top:0;** from **#resizable**

example: **http://jsbin.com/aDUMelI/1/edit**

```
$("#resizable").resizable({
    containment: "#Parent"
});
```

css:

```
#Parent {
      position: relative;
      top: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      width:auto;
      height:100%;
}

#resizable {
       display:block;
       width: 256px;
       height: 256px;
       background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Love you Jonathan. Thanks for lovely help.

Answer (score 0):

Just take off the double quotes in `"containment"` and your mother div is not `#Container`, it is `#Parent`

Your script should be,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#resizable").resizable({
        containment: "#Parent"
      });
    });
```